# Read a text file and convert to JSON in a particular format

Tags: javascript, json, text

I am reading employee details from a text file like shown below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "employees.txt",
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

It gives me response like :

```
    Mark
    Mark have 10 years of experience working with youth agencies. Mark have a bachelor’s degree in outdoor education. He raise money, train leaders, and organize units. He have raised over $100,000 each of the last six years. He consider himself a good public speaker, and have a good sense of humor.

    Jennifer
    Jennifer enjoy meeting new people and finding ways to help them have an uplifting experience. She have had a variety of customer service opportunities, through which she was able to have fewer returned products and increased repeat customers, when compared with co-workers. She is dedicated, outgoing, and a team player.
```

Now from this response I need a resultant structure like :

```
 var employees = [
   ["mark", {
      "name": "Mark",
      "description": "Mark have 10 years of experience working with youth agencies. Mark have a bachelor’s degree in outdoor education. He raise money, train leaders, and organize units. He have raised over $100,000 each of the last six years. He consider himself a good public speaker, and have a good sense of humor."
   }],
   ["jennifer", {
      "name": "Jennifer",
      "description": "Jennifer enjoy meeting new people and finding ways to help them have an uplifting experience. She have had a variety of customer service opportunities, through which she was able to have fewer returned products and increased repeat customers, when compared with co-workers. She is dedicated, outgoing, and a team player."
   }]
];
```

How can I do this? Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: expected result is not a valid json.

Comment: so after every line there is a return character (\r or \n ?) and after every record there are two line breaks?

Comment: @Jenz - so why did you show it with `\n` or `\r` characters then? The response file you've shown contains one or both.

Comment: How can we identify a double break..I tried by splitting with `\r\n` but it is not giving any result.

Comment: @Jenz - look at the file in a hex-editor and see what it contains, Why guess when you can look? 0x0A for CR or \r, 0x0D for LF or \n

Answer (score 1):

This example tested with div has your text in HTML and when we get `innerText` this returns blocks that we can split it by `\n\n`

```js
//split using \n\n

function toJson(str) {
  var tt = [];
  var rw = str.split("\n\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < rw.length; i++) {
    var name = rw[i].split("\n")[0].trim();
    var description = rw[i].split("\n")[1].trim();
    var jsn = [
      name, {
        "name": name,
        "description": description
      }
    ]
    tt.push(jsn);
  }
  return tt;
}

var employees = toJson(document.getElementById("txt").innerText);

console.log(employees);
```

```html
<div id='txt'>
  Mark
  <br/>Mark have 10 years of experience working with youth agencies. Mark have a bachelor’s degree in outdoor education. He raise money, train leaders, and organize units. He have raised over $100,000 each of the last six years. He consider himself a good
  public speaker, and have a good sense of humor.
  <br/>
  <br/>Jennifer
  <br/>Jennifer enjoy meeting new people and finding ways to help them have an uplifting experience. She have had a variety of customer service opportunities, through which she was able to have fewer returned products and increased repeat customers, when compared
  with co-workers. She is dedicated, outgoing, and a team player.
</div>
```